# Assigning a value to a colour

Tags: c

Im trying to find a way to assign a value to a specific colour/word. This is just a test code that I tried but it didnt work, any suggestions? input = green and red. output = 6.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
#define green 2, red 3;

{


    char bands, color1, color2;
    int mult;


    printf("Select how many bands the resistor has");
    printf("\n A. 4 bands");
    printf("\n B. 5 bands");
    printf("\n C. 6 bands");
    scanf("%c", &bands);

    switch (bands)

    case 'a':
    case 'A':
    printf("Enter the colors");
    scanf("%s %s", &color1, &color2);
    mult = color1 * color2;
    printf("%d", mult);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#define green 2, red 3;` this does *so* not do what you want it to do in multiple different ways. You should do some reading on the [C preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). In particular you should revisit macro syntax and realize that the *pre*processor runs before the compilation phase, so the names get lost before even compilation time (let alone run time)

Comment: Define "didn't work."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#define` directive you are will instruct the preprocessor to replace all symbols matching `green` with the string you have defined, in this case `2, red 3;`

However, there are no `green` symbols in your file, so the `#define` will not do anything.

A `#define` directive will NOT have any effect on variables. You will have to manually check variables to see if they are equal to any constants you care about. Currently your program will not execute any differently than if the `#define` line were removed. If you want to define a mapping between a string and an integer, you will need to take a different approach.

Also, your color variables need to be defined as character arrays if they are going to hold more than a single character. By specifying `%s` in scanf, you are storing multiple characters in a single character, which will cause memory corruption.

Here is a corrected version of your program with the color mapping as a function instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_COLOR_STR_LEN 10

int valueFromColor(char const * const color) 
{
  if(strcmp("green", color)==0)
    return 2;
  if(strcmp("red", color)==0)
    return 3;
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char bands;
    char color1[MAX_COLOR_STR_LEN];
    char color2[MAX_COLOR_STR_LEN];
    int mult;


    printf("Select how many bands the resistor has");
    printf("\n A. 4 bands");
    printf("\n B. 5 bands");
    printf("\n C. 6 bands");
    scanf("%c", &bands);

    switch (bands)

    case 'a':
    case 'A':
      printf("\nEnter the colors");
      scanf("%s %s", color1, color2);
      mult = valueFromColor(color1) * valueFromColor(color2);
      printf("%d", mult);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the code that I have been looking for but for some reason is not working on xCode.

Comment: I had a few bugs, including a failure to include `<string.h>` for the `strcmp()` calls. Also had to add a zero test to the `valueFromColor` function.

Answer (score 4):

When you do:

```
#define green 2, red 3;
```

You are defining a macro `green` that expands to `2, red 3;`.

What you need to do is:

```
#define green 2
#define red 3
```

But a better way is to avoid macros if you can:

```
enum { green = 2, red = 3 };
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways you can solve your problem.

**Solution 1: Use `#define` properly**

Replace

```
#define green 2, red 3;
```

by

```
#define green 2
#define red 3
```

**Solution 2: Use `const` variables**

Replace

```
#define green 2, red 3;
```

by

```
const int green = 2;
const int red = 3;
```

**Solution 3: Use an `enum`**

Replace

```
#define green 2, red 3;
```

by

```
enum KNOWN_COLORS { green=2, red };
```

Comment: I had tried using enum before and I just tried using const int, but in both case I get a weird number output "11514".

Comment: That points to an error elsewhere. I don't see any use of `green` or `red` in the code you posted. Perhaps you could add some more of your code to your question.